# is there a way in Pandas to use previous row value to compute new values for a row

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

[image]

This is AAPL daily rate of return. Suppose that I have $1 to invest initially. At the end of each day, I would also invest extra $3.

I know this is a little complicated to explain, so here are the examples

In 1/13/20, I would have `$1 * (1 + 0.0213) + 3` = `$4.02`

In 1/14/20, I would have `$4.02 * (1 - 0.013) + 3` = `$6.96`

In 1/15/20, I would have `$6.96 * (1 - 0.004) + 3` = `$9.93`

This is what it looks like in Excel.
[image]

I'm not sure how to implement this scheme in python pandas. Could somebody help me out

Comment: Hi there!, Welcome to StackOverflow. Please avoid use images in your question if it's not necessary. Instead, write your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try below `for-loop` that sums up the column like using formula in Excel:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
'Date': ['', '2020-01-13', '2020-01-14', '2020-01-15', '2020-01-16', '2020-01-17'],
'AAPL': ['', 0.021364, -0.013503, -0.004286, 0.012526, 0.011071]})
df['Portfolio'] = 1

for i in range(1, len(df)):
    df.loc[i, 'Portfolio'] = df.loc[i-1, 'Portfolio'] * (1 + df.loc[i, 'AAPL']) + 3

print(df)
```

Output

```
         Date      AAPL  Portfolio
0                         1.000000
1  2020-01-13  0.021364   4.021364
2  2020-01-14 -0.013503   6.967064
3  2020-01-15 -0.004286   9.937203
4  2020-01-16  0.012526  13.061676
5  2020-01-17  0.011071  16.206282
```